# How to compute Vds for this MOSFET transistor

Tags: mosfet

[image]

Hi. I am confused when calculating Vsd in this figure as the resistor Rgd makes it an unconventional circuit to calculate when I apply DC analysis on it. How should I go around doing this question? Is there anyway that I can thevenin's Rg2, Rg2 and Rgd together or something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a DC analysis, then you can ignore all of the nets with capacitors, and you end up with essentially a voltage divider made up of R\$_{G2}\$, R\$_{G1}\$, R\$_{GD}\$, and R\$_{D}\$.

R\$_{DS}\$ is the resistance between the drain and source; when the MOSFET is off, it is very high, when the MOSFET is on, or saturated, it is very low, the maximum value is generally given in a datasheet as R\$_{DS}\$(on).

The voltage at the drain is then:

$$V_{d} = V_{dd} \space\times\space \frac{R_{D}}{(\frac{(R_{G2}+R_{G1}+R_{GD})\space\times\space R_{DS}}{R_{G2}+R_{G1}+R_{GD}+R_{DS}})}$$

Since the voltage at the source is V\$_{dd}\$, then the voltage V\$_{sd}\$ is:

$$V_{sd} =  V_{dd} - (V_{dd} \space\times\space \frac{R_{D}}{(\frac{(R_{G2}+R_{G1}+R_{GD})\space\times\space R_{DS}}{R_{G2}+R_{G1}+R_{GD}+R_{DS}})})$$

$$          \space =  V_{dd} \space\times\space (1 - \frac{R_{D}}{(\frac{(R_{G2}+R_{G1}+R_{GD})\space\times\space R_{DS}}{R_{G2}+R_{G1}+R_{GD}+R_{DS}})})$$

Comment: Hi thanks! But for this case, you assumed the MOSFET is off(what do you mean by on or off? shouldnt it be on?), is that why you can use the voltage divider to find Vd? Because if not, Vd technically has two points, 1 from the resistors as what you calculated, and 1 more from this equation Vd = Vdd- Vsd. Are this two Vd the same or I am wrong in some way?

Comment: If a MOSFET is off, there is no current flowing from the source to the drain (essentially infinite resistance between them); when the MOSFET is on (also called saturated, or active), then it is like a closed switch except there is still a maximum resistance Rds between the drain and source, usually very small, sometimes in thousands of an ohm (milliohm).  In between these two extremes is what is called the linear or ohmic region, where the resistance between the source and drain will vary relative to the voltage applied to the gate.

Comment: So if the MOSFET is off, as I assumed, then Rds is infinite and doesn't fit into my equations.  If the MOSFET is on, then Rds would be in parallel with Rg1, Rg2, and Rgd, I guess I could update my equations to account for that since if Rds is very large, it would just default to my original ones.  I'll do that.

Comment: So in this case, I would believe that the MOSFET is on as I have small signal analysis later on. Does your equations still work?

Comment: That's what I was going to add.

Comment: Saturation region for a MOSFET is the constant current area and it isn't like a closed switch: http://macao.communications.museum/images/exhibits/2_10_4_4_eng.png

Comment: @tcrosley but in my question I am not given Rds though.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for the clarification, I'm used to thinking of them as switches because I normally just use them as digital devices, on or off.

Comment: @shooterskull I updated my equations, which should work fine for the off and on conditions (Rds = Rds(on) or Rds very high), however they will probably not be much use for you in the linear region where Rds = Vsd / Isd (where you are trying to compute Vsd).

Comment: @tcrosley using your previous equation with the resistor as a voltage divider. I have come up with this other two equations but I am not sure if they are right. Can you help me double check? I1 = Vsd/(Rg2+Rg1+Rgd) and also Vdd = Vsd + Rd(I1 + Id)

Answer (score 1):

The circuit you have has negative feedback to try and ensure the drain is set to about 50% of the power rail - so assume the drain has a quiescent voltage of half Vdd. Next, decide what drain current you wish to be flowing and this gives you the value of Rd.

You then have to calculate what dc voltage is required on the gate to achieve that drain current. Once you have that you can calculate the values of RG1, RG2 and RGD.

If you are looking for a mathematical relationship without constraining yourself to picking a drain current then I'll leave you to it because that's not how anyone would design this to operate in a practical circuit.

In other words Vsd is intentended to be half Vdd in this type of circuit.

Comment: Hi. I actually have the values of the resistors. I'm actually required to find the q point of this transistor ie Id.

Comment: So why are you not stating that in the question?

Comment: Because I'm not looking for an answer to my homework but more like hints and guide  to get there.